# Can two or more ipads be connected over Wifi?

Tags: ios, ipad, wifi

Hi guys

I was thinking of an app that would involve data transfer among  a group of ipads connected by wifi.But the more i research the more confused i become:-(.I have seen games that use two ipads connected via wifi.But in some forums  i saw the opinion that apple doesnot allow such a distribution.So you can see my problem.I cant go on with my project without solid information.What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they can although iOS doesn't give you much help. Although it looks relatively easy to do this using GameKit:

```
    GKPeerPickerController* picker = [[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline | GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby;
```

GKPeerPickerController is not actually much help. GKPeerPickerController does not include any UI to configure your "on line" settings - this means it is left up to you to provide the server and any session negotiation yourself. Finally, you will have to write the protocol between the iPads yourself.

If the iPads are going to be close to each other, you might want to use Bluetooth - note that ou must include GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby as one of the connection for the peer picker types anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the gamekit suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Bonjour framework, which is supported by iOS and was specifically developed for devices to discover and communicate with each other over a network.

Comment: The ounjour frameworks seems the way to go.Now porng over chatty